# Saving an audio file with Mediastore API throws RemoteException on API 28-

Tags: android, audio, mediastore

I didn't find any official documentation explaining how to save an audio file on the external storage with the MediaStore API.
On API 29+ everything works. On API 28- I get this error:

```
E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2036)
    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:2188)
    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:2592)
    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:1872)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:266)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:152)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

This is the code that I use (when I call "insert" I get a null Uri):

```
 //@RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.Q)
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private fun export(name: String, path: String) {
    val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
    val audioCollection =  if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    }

    val newAudioFileDetails = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, "data")
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
    }

    val recordingUri = resolver.insert(audioCollection, newAudioFileDetails)
    Log.d(TAG, "recording Uri: ${recordingUri.toString()}")
    recordingUri?.let { recordingUri ->
        resolver.openFileDescriptor(recordingUri, "w")?.use {
            val bytesCopied = File(path).inputStream().copyTo(FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor))
            Log.d("TAG", "bytes copied: $bytesCopied")
        }

        newAudioFileDetails.let {
            it.clear()
            it.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
            resolver.update(recordingUri, it, null, null)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I also tried with this, but I always get a null Uri when inserting:

```
val newAudioFileDetails = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)

        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val audioDir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "MyNewAlbumName")
            val audioPath = File(audioDir, "$name.mp3").absolutePath
            put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, audioPath)
        }
```

Comment: You have a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: `......Media.DATA, "data"` ?  What should that be? You have to supply a path.

Comment: what path do I have to supply?

Comment: The StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown by the ContentResolver class: I simply get a null Uri in return

Comment: The path where your file should be saved. Full path of directory. Or full path of file. Try both.

Comment: I tried, with no luck (see edited question). Btw, the field DATA is also deprecated, but you have to use it because otherwise you get an exception on APIs 28-. Why don't they write a decent documentation on how to use that API?

Comment: For Android devices < 29 you still have to use thr .DATA column.

Comment: Why are you trying to update Mediastore. Android will do this for you through the scanning process

Comment: Because that's the way recommended by the official docs. Anyway I gave up: now on API 28- I save the audio file in the download folder and my code looks like: if (androidVersion >= 29) ... else ...